# Require.js configure "paths" when namespaces overlapped

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to migrate our project to Require.js, but met a problem dealing with mapping module locations.

The result I'm expecting is that I want module `some/foo.js` goes to `dir1/some/foo.js`,
and all modules in namespace `some/foo/` goes to `dir2/some/foo/`. Just like below:(Maybe it's not a good convention to have namespaces like that, but what can I do?)

```
require.config({
  "paths":{
    "some/foo":"dir1/some/foo",
    "some/foo/*":"dir2/some/*"
  }
});
```

How am I supposed to accomplish this with Require.js?